# Expression of type System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory cannot be used for return type System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3 razor project. my solution was running correctly but now it compile correctly but show error at run time. Following error is show please give me help to resolve it.

```
Expression of type 'System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory' cannot be used for return type 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor.WebRazorHostFactory'
```

Source Error:

```
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below
```